# How to avoid affecting other queries when using posts_orderby?

Tags: wpml, wordpress

In WordPress as you must already known, when using [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) or [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) or even [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), it is not possible to order the returned posts by specifying a list of post ID in the order we want.

Instead we have to loop through the results and re-order them on the PHP side. This is a performance hit and a bad practice. Instead we should use built-in MySQL functions to retrieve the posts in the desired order upfront.

Thankfully there is the [`posts_orderby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) which can be used to specify a custom ORDERBY statement, like this:

```
// My list of post IDs in my custom order
$my_post_ids = array(1,3,2);

// Apply filter to the ORDERBY SQL statement
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_custom_orderby');
function my_custom_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $my_post_ids;
    $orderby_statement = 'FIELD(ID, '.implode(',',$my_post_ids).')';     
    return $orderby_statement;
}

// My custom query
$my_custom_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => $my_post_ids);
```

However there is a problem with the above code, is that it will affect the order of **all** queries on the page! Including queries made by plugins, shortcodes, and so on.

## Easy fix!

The simple way to fix this, is to apply the filter only one time, and remove it as soon as it is called, by putting a `remove_filter()` within the filter itself, so it is run only once:

```
// My list of post IDs in my custom order
$my_post_ids = array(1,3,2);

// Apply filter to the ORDERBY SQL statement
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_custom_orderby');
function my_custom_orderby($orderby_statement) {

    // Disable this filter for future queries!
    remove_filter(current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);

    global $my_post_ids;
    $orderby_statement = 'FIELD(ID, '.implode(',',$my_post_ids).')';     
    return $orderby_statement;
}

// My custom query
$my_custom_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => $my_post_ids);
```

Because I set this filter just before my custom query, once I execute my custom query it should be filtered by the `posts_orderby` filter set above, which is then immediately disabled so it won't affect any future queries.

In theory, that's great, and it works great in most case scenarios!

## An issue with WPML

However I have encountered a case when using the [WPML plugin](http://wpml.org/) where this filter affects other queries than mine and causes errors. I believe the WPML plugin is creating a query of its own that is executed just before my own custom query, making my filter applies to the WPML query instead of mine!

**Is there any possible way to add a check within the filter to make sure that it affects the correct query?**

Thank you very much

---

Edit:

## The fix for WPML

For information, while the accepted answer for this question is correct, it didn't solve the problem I was having with WPML. Here is how I fixed the WPML conflict:

```
// My list of post IDs in my custom order
$my_post_ids = array(1,3,2);

// Apply filter to the ORDERBY SQL statement
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_custom_orderby');
function my_custom_orderby($orderby_statement) {

    // Disable this filter for future queries!
    remove_filter(current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);

    global $my_post_ids, $wpdb;
    $orderby_statement = 'FIELD('.$wpdb->base_prefix.'posts.ID, '.implode(',',$my_post_ids).')';     
    return $orderby_statement;
}

// My custom query
$my_custom_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => $my_post_ids);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This filter [takes two parameters](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/query.php#L2605), `$orderby` and `&$this`. "this" being the WP_Query object. I'm not sure how to detect that WPML is making the call, but we can check that *your* call is the one being
made.

```
$my_post_ids = array(1,3,2);

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_custom_orderby', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_orderby( $orderby_statement, $object ) 
{
    global $my_post_ids;
    if( $my_post_ids != $object->query['post__in'] )
        return $orderby_statement;

    // Disable this filter for future queries!
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    $orderby_statement = 'FIELD(ID, ' . implode( ',', $my_post_ids ) . ')';     
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have accepted your answer and will provide you the +50 bounty reputation as soon as it will allow me. For information, **this did not solve my issue with WPML**, but is still a correct answer for my question. I was able to solve my issue by replacing `ID` with `'.$wpdb->base_prefix.'posts.ID` in the statement. Because WPML makes a JOIN on each query (to get the translation from a different table I guess) having the "ID" by itself caused a MySQL error as it didn't know to which table the ID field was pertaining, therefore adding the table fixed it!

Comment: Glad to know my input helped to solve the issue ;) Maybe you can write an Answer with your solution and mark it as the correct one, or feel free to edit mine and adapt it.